# Tips for reviving downed teammates near walls/cover?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Reviving downed teammates out in the open is no problem, but sometimes my comrades will suffer a mishap while beside a piece of cover. When this happens, I seem to be more likely to roll around like a Gears of War player or take cover myself than revive anyone.

**Does anyone have tips on reviving teammates near cover?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing is to be looking directly at them.  If your crosshairs are lined up with the circle with the "revive" icon, you'll be much more likely to revive rather than stick to the wall or start sprinting/rolling.

Sometimes though, you'll glitch or you can't quite get lined up.  In single player, I tend to just say "aww, forget this" and use Medigel.  This isn't so much an option in co-op though. :)

Note also that reviving seems to make you slightly taller than the "low" chest-high cover walls, and that it will also break you out of cover when you finish reviving.  Make sure you head for cover immediately afterwards, lest you end up needing first aid yourself.  :)

Comment: Medigel wouldn't help much on Multiplayer though!

Comment: @mike1987, this is very true :)  I had assumed single player, since I've had more glitchy experiences in there than in multiplayer.  I'll make sure that's clearer in my answer.

Comment: I left it open since I've had problems in both MP and SP :-).

Answer (score 3):

I personally find that looking **AWAY** from cover is the best.

Go near cover, look at your team mate and try to have your back to it, You crouch whilst reviving a team mate so in effect you can often get away with using the cover to your advantage *whilst* you revive your team mate.

Not moving whilst you press it helps.

I do this and it works 99% of the time. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try and look at the character, not the wall. Make sure you stop moving before you press the Revive key, or you're a lot more likely to try and "stick" to cover if you're moving toward the cover, or even roll away if you're moving away from cover.

Try standing a bit away from cover as well; try and make sure you're closer to your teammate than to the wall, even if this means you're a bit more in the open; it only takes ~2 seconds to revive someone.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you expect to stick to the cover, as i have started doing. just assuming i will stick to cover allows me to bounce right off it then revive just as fast as taking the time to look at them face away from cover and cough 3 times to get it to work.